# Should I inform my previous supervisor of my paper published?

Tags: research-process, paper-submission, supervision

I was taking a PHD research in engineering at a university and used an advanced method to obtain the results. But my supervisor didn’t accept my results and paper manuscripts. I then used another traditional method to complete my research. However,after graduation I immediately submitted my paper with that advanced method and it was successfully accepted and published by a famous international journal in only submission with a little bit wording revisions. My question is: would you suggest if I need to tell my supervisor about that new publication? If yes, how can I mention that? As the Christmas is coming I may send a seasonal greeting to that supervisor. Thank you for your help! Cheers, Donny.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?  is this just to gloat?

Comment: Your supervisor was not listed as a co-author and was never intended to be a co-author of this work?

Comment: Hi VitaminE, thank you for your comment. No any gloating at all. I just felt in a dilemma situation to tell  or not tell. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Snijderfrey, I appreciated your comments. My supervisor didn’t recognise the method used and was not intended to be a coauthor. Regards, Donny

Comment: @Don, please use an @ before the username to make sure people get a notification that they are addressed. This increases your chances to get a reply.

Comment: @Snijderfrey, thank you for your reminding me of the use of @. I am new and learnt, regards, Don.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the same field, I'm sure your previous supervisor will come across it anyways. I think relations with this colleague would be best if you proactively share it with them. Of course there are strong preferences and stylistic tendencies in analytical methods -- as long as your email doesn't take an "i told you so" tone, then I think it is a good idea to contact them.

Comment: Hello littleraspberry, welcome to this forum, both you and I are new here. I appreciated your suggestion and would take your advice into my consideration. Cheers, Donny.